# I edited vim configuration file and error occured (on MS Windows, error says "don't know "%\" option)

Tags: java, vim, compilation

I'm using ms windows
First, I'm really novice in programming and linux and so many question is here, I'm sorry

I wanted to comfile java source code on gvim and searched googled.. found a post and found some code "myjava.vim", his configuration and _vimrc code

and error occured

here is myjava.vim
this if config file for java

~/.vim/myjava.vim

---

```
set cindent
set smartindent
set ai
syntax on

" indent config
set sw=4 sts=4 ts=8 et

" compile and execution
map <F6> :!java %:r<SPACE>
map <F7> :w<ENTER>:make<ENTER>

" compile config
set makeprg=javac %\
set errorformat=%A%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#

" finding compile error
map ,n :cn<ENTER>
map ,p :cp<ENTER>
map ,l :cl<ENTER>
map ,w :cw<ENTER>

" set block and auto annotation
vmap ,c :s/^/\/\//g<ENTER>
vmap ,uc :s/^\/\///g<ENTER>

" TagList config
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :Tlist<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :w<CR>:TlistUpdate<CR>
let Tlist_Inc_Winwidth=0
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window=1

" ctags config
set tags=~/.javatags
set complete=.,w,b,u,t,i

" abbreviation config
ab sysout System.out.println();<ESC>hi
ab syserr System.out.println();<ESC>hi
ab debug if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {<CR>log.debug();<CR>}<CR><ESC>kkf(a
```

---

in line 14 error occured "don't know %\ option"

and here is _vimrc code
I didn't know where do I have to place this code in _vimrc file and just put in the end.

---

```
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd="C:\Programs\ctags554\ctags.exe"

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.java :source ~/.vim/myjava.vim
```

---

I chanded ~/.vim/myjava.vim to C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\myjava.vim
I don't know this is right

this is my _vimrc file
_vimrc reads myjava.vim automatically when reading *.java files

---

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction


let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd="C:\Programs\ctags554\ctags.exe"

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.java :source C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\myjava.vim
```

---

I made myjava.vim and put it in vim74 folder and edited _vimrc file in Vim folder

and I opened any java file, Windows said we don't know "%\ option"

Please correct my code error.
Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: This isn’t really a Java question.  You are more likely to get an answer if you ask it on http://vi.stackexchange.com .

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer if it actually did solve the problem.  Mainly for two reasons: 1. if someone finds this question by googling he will see that it was solved; 2. You gain reputation by accepting answers :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is actually an escaping problem.  Inside a `set` in Vim you need to escape spaces:

```
set makeprg=javac\ %
```

Is the correct `makeprg` setup.  `%` is the filename of the current buffer being edited.

Moreover, have a look at your `$VIMRUNTIME` variable (just do `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` in Vim to find it).  It is likely that on your system that variable amounts to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74`

This way you can do the `autocmd` as follows:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.java :source $VIMRUNTIME/myjava.vim
```

Vim uses the forward slash even on MS windows (unless it is in a string that is passed to the command line, or `shellslash` is set).

---

Finally, @VGR is right it is much faster to get Vim answers on http://vi.stackexchange.com (our Vim part of the website)